# Yii EGMap Extension, Adding Animation

Tags: google-maps, animation, google-maps-api-3, yii

I am using the Yii Extension EGMap and it's working well.  Except that I can't get the markers to animate.

Attempt 1: 
`$marker = new EGMapMarker($latitude, $longitude, array('title'=>'Your Location','icon'=>$icon, 'shadow'=>true, 'animation'=>'google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE'));`

Attempt 2: 
`$marker->animation = 'google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE';`

Attempt 3:
`$marker = new EGMapMarker($latitude, $longitude, array('title'=>'Your Location','icon'=>$icon, 'shadow'=>true, 'animation'=>TRUE));`

Also if someone has worked with this and knows how to get this working and in addition a "pulse" that would be awesome.  Thanks!

Comment: I think you can have `.gif` animated images on your map, with this make your pulse effect

Answer (score 0):

```
'animation'=> EGMapMarker::BOUNCE
```

in more detail:
reffering to
https://github.com/2amigos/egmap/blob/master/EGMapMarker.php

```
class EGMapMarker extends EGMapBase {

    const DROP = 'google.maps.Animation.DROP';
    const BOUNCE = 'google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE';

    protected $options = array(...

 /**
 * Sets the animation to the marker when it is rendered to the map
 * @param string $animation 
 */
public function setAnimation( $animation=self::DROP )
{
    if($animation==self::DROP || $animation==self::BOUNCE)
        $this->options['animation'] = $animation;
    else
        $this->options['animation'] = self::DROP;
}
```

the correct syntax should be:

```
$marker = new EGMapMarker(
  $latitude, 
  $longitude, 
  array(
    'title' => 'Your Location',
    'icon' => $icon, 
    'shadow' => true, 
    'animation' => EGMapMarker::BOUNCE
));
```

This variant works:

```
Yii::import('ext.egmap.*');


$gMap = new EGMap();
$gMap->zoom = 10;
$gMap->setCenter(51.245475,6.821373);

$marker = new EGMapMarker(51.245475,6.821373,
  array(
    'title' => 'Your Location',
  )
);

$marker->setAnimation(EGMapMarker::BOUNCE);

$gMap->addMarker($marker);

$gMap->renderMap();
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Answer is updated for more details. Author already made some attempts in right direction, so short version should help him to correct syntax.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but that still does not work for me. It just appears. It does show the shadow though, so only the BOUNCE or DROP are not working.

Comment: Bouncing example added to answer